# sendmail.php not sending textbox data of form

Tags: php, email

I am trying this sendemail.php script. It is sending mail but it is not sending data entered in the textboxes of the form.

sendemail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent! We Will get back to you soon. :)'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
// $name = $_POST['name']; 
// $email = $_POST['email']; 
// $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
// $message = $_POST['message']; 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'dhaval@geekslabstudios.com' . ' , ' ;
$email_to .='kamal@geekslabstudios.com';

$body =  'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
?>
```

index.html form

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <textarea id="message" name="message"  required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

It sends mail but i receives like this:

Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

Comment: Try to move  and place `header('Content-type: application/json');` after this line `$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');`

Comment: Just tried it Still sends the messege but not the text fields.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and see if it contains proper fields at all.

Comment: @RomanHocke could you elaborate please.

Comment: Well, at the beginning, after the `<?php`, add `var_dump($_POST); die();` and see, what it contains, if it contains the fields You want. If You are not sure, paste the result here. Then we can see, what to try next.

Comment: @RomanHocke i am very new to php , sorry for the trouble but  please tell me how to see what var_dump($_POST) contains.

Comment: It should show up in Your browser :-) If You send the form in normal way. Or do You send it using some sort of Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks good in your code.

If you are getting mail in your inbox that means your mail function is working correctly. You should check what values you are getting in `$_POST`. If you are sending your request using `AJAX` than check your JavaScript code. Or post here for better understanding of problem.